# NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream Tomcat9 jdk1.8.0_281

Tags: java, email, tomcat9

I need a little help to understand an error which, I hope, will be easy to solve for experienced developper :)

I developp a Java EE application, I just reinstalled my server (ubuntu) and now my application cannot send e-mail.

From my local environnement I still can send e-mail (Eclipse, Tomcat9, jdk1.8.0_281).
But from my server I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;Lcom/sun/mail/util/MailLogger;)V
                at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.initStreams(SMTPTransport.java:2016)
                at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1936)
                at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
```

I cannot understand because my server also run tomcat9 and I specialy installed jdk1.8.0_281.
(I installed the jdk and set JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281 in /etc/default/tomcat9)

I export my project from Eclipse, it should have all the lib, and I cannot see what is different in the two environnement.

Do you have any suggestion or solution?
Thank you, and I wish you a happy new year !

Adrien

**Edit following Matt advise**
So I added -verbose:class to java parameter, both in my local dev environnement et on my server, and look for intersting classes for our purpose. As you guessed there is a gap between the two environments, here :

```
On Local PC:
    [Loaded com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream from file:/D:/EclipseWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/lib/javax.mail.jar]
     
On Ubuntu Server    
    [2022-01-03 20:21:28] [info] [Loaded com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream from file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/MyApp%23%232.02/WEB-INF/lib/mailapi.jar]
```

Comment: Please add you dependencies to your question: you certainly have the same classes multiple times among your dependencies.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your help. So I try to delete mailapi.jar. The problem is that I have no dependencies management: I just drag and drop jar into lib directory. What is the easiest way to manage properly the dependencies?

Comment: Dependency management is never easy (e.g. dependency management systems have no way of knowing that [`mailapi`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/mailapi) contains a subset of the classes of [`javax.mail`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail)), but Maven/Gradle can solve many problems automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and time, I will look Maven or Gradle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your dependencies it's difficult to say what the issue is, but your version of Java is irrelevant for this issue.

Most likely the compiled and deployed version of your app is using a different version of JavaMail or another dependency than you have locally, and this deployed version doesn't have that method.

Add the Java option `-verbose:class` and it'll tell you what classes are being loaded, then grep for `TraceInputStream` or  `SMTPTransport`. Do the same on your server and locally and compare the versions.

Comment: Hi Matt! Thank you for your help. You're right, TraceInputStream is not loaded from the same library depending on the environnement. It's weird for me, for me the jdk, my app and the lib are the same, I don't understand why the behavior differs.

Comment: Now, I can try to delete mailapi.jar : javax.mail.jar is may be enough, and it will force to use TraceInputStream  from javax.mail.jar in the both environment. Do you have another suggestion? Thank you

Comment: I would suggest using Maven or Gradle to handle all builds, in which case you can pin versions and avoid issues like this.

Comment: Hi ! All seems to work without mailapi.jar. Or, to be more precise, I meet another error more probably linked with setting of SMTP server. Thank to you, I will be able to debug this kind or problem now, thank you ! And I will try to manage my lib in a better way :)